# Open files, copy area under header, print to mastersheet

Tags: vba, excel

This loops through folder to open files and get important info from the columns of names "HOLDER" and "CUTTING TOOL" and printing all the info to one excel document, masterfile.

It utilizes a dictionary and collection. I am very new to VBA So I do not know if I have stayed consistent with my naming of sheets and files and using the code to make the program work as fast as possible.

Any tips on how to streamline the code more?

```
    Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim RowLast As Long
    Dim f As String
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, d As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    'find the headers on the sheet
    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 2


    'loop through directory file and print names
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
'(2)

            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet
'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
                Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")
                If Not hc Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the masterfile, column 3
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If
'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                Set hc3 = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "HOLDER")
                If Not hc3 Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If
'(5)
            With WB
               'print TDS information
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                        'print the file name to Column 1
                        StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Name
                        'print TDS name from J1 cell to Column 4
                        With ws
                            .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Cells(i, 4)
                        End With
                        i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                'move to next file
                Next ws
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
'(7)
End Sub

'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, rng As Range, c As Range, v
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 And Not dict.exists(v) Then
            dict.Add c.Address, v
        End If
    Next c
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function

'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        If Trim(c.Value) = sHeader Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function

'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
```

Comment: Can you provide small generic test files that would allow me to run the code?

Comment: I can do that! Do you know what would be the best way to make those files available to you? @paulbica

Comment: You can send them to dexxus@rogers.com (I'm not sure if there are better ways)

Answer (score 3):

I've got the following points to make which are mostly about style and readability rather than the speed of the code.

1. Why not use early binding for the Microsoft Scripting Runtime? This will let declare variables such as `FileSystemObject` and as `Dictionary` rather than as `Object`.
2. Some of your functions do not state the return type, e.g. `GetLastRowInSheet` and `GetLastRowInColumn` should both return a Long I guess and `GetValues` should return a Dictionary.
3. Variable declaration. Personally, I always declare each variable on a separate line but if you want to condense them, then I'd suggest grouping them by type. In `GetValues` you mix variable types which makes it harder than it should to check the type of a variable.
4. Variable naming. Perhaps consider using more meaningful variable names. `Dim d As Range` doesn't really convey the meaning.
5. In the `HeaderCell` function you loop through cells looking at their value. If you use the `Range.Find` method it will probably be much quicker.

   ```
   Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
   Set HeaderCell = rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) _
       .Find(What:=sHeader, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPartial, MatchCase:=True)
   End Function
   ```
6. In the `GetLastRowInSheet` function you use the WorksheetFunction and Find methods. The former is quite slow. Consider using the `UsedRange` property of the Worksheet object.

   ```
   Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet) As Long
       With theWorksheet.UsedRange
           GetLastRowInSheet = (.Row + .Rows.Count)
       End With
   End Function
   ```
7. In your section (5) you've got `With WB ... End With` but I think it doesn't add much but increases the level of indentation.

Comment: Be careful with `UsedRange`, it can sometimes return surprising results. ++ Nice review.

Comment: @RubberDuck - I see you changed my paragraph numbering from "N)" to "N." I'm curious why? Thanks

Comment: It makes it an actual markdown numbered list, which in turn gets transformed into an HTML ordered list. Just nicer formatting. It makes your answer more readable.